# RecyclerView is empty when restoring fragment from backStack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` in a Fragment and initially is hidden. When user clicks a button, I set visibility to true for the `RecyclerView` and I display some data I have on an `ArrayList`.

The problem starts when I move another fragment on top (I add the previous fragment with the `RecyclerView` in the backStack) : if I click back from the new fragment the previous fragment (the one with the `RecyclerView` ) is visible and in `onCreateView()` I log the values of the dataSet I'm using for the recyclerView and everything is there, but the recyclerView is empty ( only footer item is presented ).

If we call `RvFragment` the Fragment with the `RecyclerView` and `NextFragment` the fragment that comes to the backstack and then leaves the schema is :

```
                                     (back pressed)
RvFragment ----------> NextFragment  ------------> RvFragment
```

and here's the code from `onCreateView()` :

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo_comments, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    Timber.i("onCreateView data.size == %d", commentArrayList.size());

    setToolbarTitle();

    Picasso.with(getActivity())
            .load(photo)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_timeline_image_placeholder)
            .centerCrop()
            .fit()
            .into(ivPhoto);

    if (hasCommentsVisible) {
        Timber.i("comments are visible!! and dataSize == %d", commentArrayList.size());
        llFlagsCommentsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rvCommentsList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    tvComments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            hasCommentsVisible = true;
            llFlagsCommentsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rvCommentsList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    initRecyclerView();

    return view;
}
```

You can see with the log statements in the code above I can confirm the data exist. Thanks!

Comment: When and how do you populate `commentArrayList` ?

Comment: Inside `onCreate()` I start a `Retrofit` call and receive the data in a method :    `@Override
    public void showData(Comment comment) {
        commentArrayList.add(comment);
        adapter.addItem(comment);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand how you set up your fragment stack but just to be sure : onCreateView won't be called again when you press the back button if the fragment is still on the stack.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace

```
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

Only onStart() will.

If you want onCreateView to be called again then you need to use the

```
FragmentTransaction.replace(NextFragment)
```

without the addToBackStack() but it means the whole fragment will be recreated from scratch. Probably not what you want, especially if you are getting your data from a webservice.

Alternatively, to fully recreate your fragment every time you come back to it, you can simply remove it entirely :

```
FragmentTransaction.remove(RvFragment)
```

and then push your next fragment

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm using a library named [FragNav](https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav) to save Fragments into back stack. So what really happens is that the view only is destroyed and the instance vars persist (and that's why I can see the logs and tell that commentsArrayList is not empty )